# Interpolation error when setting maximum for an input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The problem here is the `max="{{vm.maxAgriWomenBudget(year)}}"` inside of input is showing this error `Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{vm.maxAgriWomenBudget(year)}} TypeError: Cannot read property '2016' of undefined` 2016 is the (year) argument inside `vm.maxAgriWomenBudget(year)` which gets an object that contains years(keys) and its value(that should me max in input) and if year is not defined returns 0.

```
vm.argiterraYearlyLocalCost = {}; // intialised at the top in controller
function maxAgriWomenBudget (year) {
        return angular.isDefined(vm.argiterraYearlyLocalCost[year]) ? vm.argiterraYearlyLocalCost[year]:0;
    }
```

In the start `vm.yearlyLocalCost[year]` is empty object, but as I add stuff the object fills up. So I made function to check if vm.yearlyLocalCost[year] is not defined then return 0.

```
<md-input-container flex>
                          <label translate>PROJECT.WIZARD.BUDGET.WOMEN_BUDGET_ARGITERRA</label>
                          <input name="genderBudgetAgriWomenBudgetYearly_{{year}}"
                                 ng-model="genderBudget.agriWomenBudgetYearly"
                                 placeholder="Budget spent on women reached of yearly cost contributed by Agriterra "
                                 ng-click="vm.showExplanation('ADVISE_BUDGET_AMOUNT')"
                                 ain-numbers-only
                                 max="{{(vm.yearlyLocalCost[year] || 0)}}"
                                 type="text">

 </md-input-container>
```

Comment: use ng-maxlength instead of max.

Comment: max is for the input field with type "number" not "text"

Comment: @Natchkebiailia true it works only if click on the range button to set the number, but if I type the number it does not control.

Comment: HTML input type number does not control max value when it is typed.(see here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_max_min) It should be done in controller

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing `vm.argiterraYearlyLocalCost` at the top but then referencing `vm.yearlyLocalCost`  in your function below.  Use the same identifier in both places and that error should go away.  The error is because `yearlyLocalCost` is not a property of `vm`.

Comment: true @jlew, very dumb of me, I changed it but now type error still remains. Interpolate error is gone.